# Scala: Convert a csv string to Array

Tags: arrays, string, scala, split, scala-collections

I tried to convert a scala string to array by splitting it by `,`.For example:

```
var string = "a,b,c,d,"
array =  string.split(",")
arr: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)
```

But the output I am getting is `Array(a, b, c, d)`, instead of `Array(a, b, c, d, )`. The last comma in the string is ignored by the split method. Is there any other method to solve this problem?.I presume this is trivial one, but I am new to scala. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use split with `-1` argument.

```
string.split(",",-1)
```

To understand what the `-1` argument means, let's look at the method signature

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)
```

The **limit** parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most (n - 1) times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.

**If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length**. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Examples:

```
scala> val myString = "a,b,c,d,,," 
scala> val stringSplit = myString.split(",")
scala> arr: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)
```

If this time we specify the limit

```
scala> val myString = "a,b,c,d,,," 
scala> val stringSplitWithLimit = myString.split(",", -1)
scala> arr: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d, "", "", "")
```

This behavior comes from Java (since Scala uses Java Strings). [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) is the documentation directly out of Javadoc.

Comment: Thanks @marios . Can you explain, what does the second parameter do?

Answer (score 2):

In general case, csv is not just a list of strings with commas. For example:

```
 1,2,"3aa,bbb 
    cc\"c", 4
 5,6,7,8
```

is totally correct CSV file

So it's better to use some external parser, like this one: https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv